# Using bash, how to change the name of a file based on feedback from PHP script?

Tags: php, bash, curl

I have git bash and I am making commits using it. I need however, to make the .bashrc alias, that will also run a php script, return a value N (which is a number) from that script, and use that value Nto change the name of a file like so:

```
nameOfFileN
```

How do I do this? I need this sequence of commands. It is my local windows machine. I have php installed. I use windows git bash to use git. I want to run this in it (in the git bash). I need this bash command together with the php file that just returns an echo-ed variable value.

Comment: Is it a local script? Is it hosted on a webserver? Is it hosted locally? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: it is one my local windows machine. I don't know how to try it.

Comment: Is it hosted and accessible via webserver (e.g. nginx or apache) or do you want to run it on the CLI directly? You have to give us more information if you want us to be able to help.

Comment: No, it is my local windows machine. I have php installed. I use windows git bash to use git. I want to run this in it ( in the git bash).

Comment: Please see my question, I updated it.

Comment: That still does not answer the question Webserver vs CLI. Do you want to run `php /path/to/script.php` or do you want to run `curl http://localhost/path/to/script.php`?

Comment: @knittl either solution would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your PHP script is hosted in a webserver, use `curl`:

  ```
  curl http://localhost/path/to/script.php
  ```
- If it is a stand-alone script and you have the PHP CLI interpreter installed, run the script directly:

  ```
  php /path/to/script.php
  ```

Both calls will give you the output of the PHP script. Use it however you need (pipe it to another process, redirect it to a file, use it for command substitution, assign it to a shell variable, …)